# How to encode bytes to a string in Java

Tags: java, string, byte, encode

I am trying to encode bytes from an inputstream to plain text characters. So, I made the string out of ints seperated by spaces, like this:

```
InputStream in;
//etc
int b;
String finalString="";
while((b=in.read())!=-1)finalString+=""+b+" ";
in.close()
```

But the problem is, this makes the string 3-4 times larger than the original bytes. Is there any other way of encoding bytes to plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to transform binary data into plain text. You should use Base64 for that. The loss factor will only be 4/3.

Apache commons-codec has a free implementation of a Base64 encoder (and decoder).

Another possibility is Hex encoding (which commons-codec also supports), but it needs 2 bytes of text for each byte of binary data.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get it all into a single `byte[]`, then this should just be

```
new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```

or whatever character encoding you expect the input to use.

Comment: This also has the advantage of not doing repeated string concatenation, since Java has only immutable strings that would be less efficient.

Comment: To be fair, reading the input into a `byte[]` has similar difficulties.  That said, it's fairly straightforward with utilities like [`ByteStreams.toByteArray(InputStream)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)) with Guava.

Comment: It would, but at least you can allocate some predetermined amount of space, and expansions usually go further than one byte at a time ;)

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is after. If I understood correctly, he wants to transform binary data into plain text.

Comment: ...I'm not convinced the OP knows _what_ they're after, in all honesty.  My best guess is that they want "any reversible way of converting bytes to text."

Comment: Then, your answer doesn't really qualify. All sequences of bytes don't constitute valid UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Hmmmm. I vaguely recall at least one of the UTF encodings always produces output, if gibberish.

Comment: I don't think that's true. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode says: *Certain noncharacter code points are guaranteed never to be used for encoding characters.*

Comment: Okay, conceded...but I still claim this answer is accurate depending on what the OP actually means, which remains unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the bytes and out them into a byte array, and then create the string using the byte array.

i.e.

```
String newString = new String(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution produces strings that are 3..4 times longer than what's in the file because it concatenates decimal character codes into a string.

Java provides a way of reading strings from streams without the need for writing loops, like this:

```
InputStream in;
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF8"));
String s = r.readLine();
```

Comment: Without loops?  What if there is more than one line?

Comment: @ametren OP's snippet reads only one string. For multiline files, you can use [`readAllLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to avoid a reading loop.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html)

For example if your string is UTF8:

```
byte[] bytes = // you got that from somewhere...
String x = new String(bytes, "UTF8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Commons-codec has [methods](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29) to encode bytes to Base64 encoding.

```
encodedText = new String(
                 org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(byteArray));
```